# Is it necessary to use a OR-operator (|) in regex expression to match unordered substrings?

Tags: python, regex, tokenize, lexical-analysis

When running lexical analysis in python for C programming language, I encountered the following trouble:

The integer type can end with a `u`(`U`) , `l`(`L`) modifier or both, in any order to specify `unsigned` or `long` type for an integer.

I am now writing regex to match this type and then scan for tokenization, the regex I wrote is as following:

```
    '''Dec'''
    r'\b([1-9][0-9]*)[uU]?[lL]?\b|\b([1-9][0-9]*)[lL][uU]\b'
    '''Oct'''
    r'\b0[0-7]*[uU]?[lL]?\b|\b0[0-7]*[lL][uU]\b'
    '''hex'''
    r'\b0[xX][a-fA-F0-9]+[uU]?[lL]?|\b0[xX][a-fA-F0-9]+[lL]?[uU]?'
```

As we can see here, to match `u` and `l` modifier in both order `ul` or `lu`(upper or lower case), I have to write an OR operator `|` in regex and repeat other parts to cover these two condition.

Is there a simple elegant way to write a regex to match two unordered parts without repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the group only at the *end* of your pattern, like so:

```
([lL][uU]|[uU]?[lL]?)
```

This covers all five cases: `(blank)`, `l`, `u`, `lu` and `ul`.

For example, your original pattern:

```
r'\b([1-9][0-9]*)[uU]?[lL]?\b|\b([1-9][0-9]*)[lL][uU]\b'
```

Becomes:

```
r'\b([1-9][0-9]*)([lL][uU]|[uU]?[lL]?)\b'
```

Note that you could simplify this further by using a case-insensitive regex:

```
'''Dec'''
re.compile('\b([1-9][0-9]*)(lu|u?l?)\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Similarly, for the other number formats we get:

```
'''Oct'''
re.compile('\b0[0-7]*(lu|u?l?)\b', re.IGNORECASE)
'''Hex'''
re.compile('\b0x[a-f0-9]+(lu|u?l?)\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: It is much more elegant to use parentheses indeed, but I am still wondering  if the OR-operator(|) is necessary for unordered matching? To be generic and universal, do we have to write a regex with two different order to match different patterns?

Comment: Regular expressions don't *really* support "unordered matching"; that's not how they fundamentally work. You can achieve this with look-aheads, but the result is rather ugly. `(lu|u?l?)` could be replaced with something like: `(?=[^l]*l?[^l]*\b)(?=[^u]*u?[^u]*\b)[lu]*`.

Comment: I think `(lu|u?l?)` is quite a simple and elegant solution to solve your problem, to be honest!